# Get URL from text using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a block of text with tags and garbage in it. Inside this block is a youtube video link i want to get which always starts with ('http://www.youtube and always ends with ',

I am looking for a regular expression that would extract the url. thanks!

this is what i have:

```
((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*[^']
```

Comment: you need to show us whatever you have tried so we can correct you..

Comment: Here's some information on regular expressions for JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Something like this    watch?v\=(.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex...

`www.youtube[^']*`

`[^']` matches any character except `'`

`[^']*` matches 0 to many characters except `'`

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'd say that lookahead is even useless because `[^']` will do the job.